# What is the $n$-th derivative of $f(t) = \log(\log(1/t))$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm trying to calculate de $n$-th derivative of $f(t)=\log(\log(1/t))$.

Wolfram Matematica gives me

$$f'(t)=-\frac{1}{t \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}$$
$$f''(t)=\frac{1}{t^2 \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}-\frac{1}{t^2 \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}$$

$$f'''(t)=-\frac{2}{t^3 \log ^3\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}+\frac{3}{t^3 \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}-\frac{2}{t^3 \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}$$

$$f''''(t)=-\frac{6}{t^4 \log ^4\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}+\frac{12}{t^4 \log ^3\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}-\frac{11}{t^4 \log ^2\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}+\frac{6}{t^4 \log \left(\frac{1}{t}\right)}$$

and I wonder whether  the numerator sequence are any known numbers as Bernoulli, Euler, Bell...

Any help is welcomed .

Comment: This sequence on OEIS has the coefficients without the signs: https://oeis.org/A188881

Comment: Stirling numbers. It's always Stirling numbers.

Comment: Many thaks !! I've been able to get a closed form.

Comment: I'm curious, what is the closed form ?